Can not access html element with javascript function
I have a simple html file with labels and text fields with ids (like firstname id=“fn”, lastname id=“ln”, and address id=“add”).   So far, my web app runs fine with inline Javascript that gets the value of these elements and stores them in a Google sheet. So far, “nothing” I try will let me getElementById with the script.   It’s the “exact” same code, but one runs inline with the HTML file, and the other runs in an HTML file in the web app as Google script.
I have tried every way possible to getElementById in my script, and I always get the same answer, which is

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstName')

This is the simple code:
  var userInfo = {};
  userInfo.firstName = document.getElementById("fn").value;

This code is to be executed when the user types in his name and address and then clicks the button when done.
Javascript (HTML) File
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff );  

    function doStuff() {
      let userInfo = {};
      userInfo.uName =  document.getElementById("username").value   
      google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
      document.getElementById("username").value = "";
    }
    </script>

CSS Style File
    <style>
      .form-row {
         margin-bottom:12px;
         text-align:center;
      }

      .sHDR {
         font-size: 28px;
         text-align:center;
      }
      .owner {
         font-size: 18px;
         border-bottom:solid;
      }
      .addr {
         font-size: 18px;
         text-align:center;
      }
      .nNote {
        text-align:center;
      }
    </style>

HTML File
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <label>Name: </label><input type="text" id="username">
      <button id="btn">Run It!</button>    
    </body>
    </html>

code.gs File
    function doGet (){
    // Logger. log(parameter);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
    }

    function userClicked(name) {
    Logger.log(name + " clicked the Button");
    document.getElementById(name).value = "";
}


Please provide the html and provide a [mcve] so that we can reproduce the problem

Thank you for your response.   Obviously I’m a newbie when it comes to integrating HTML, Javascript (JQuery), CSS, Google Apps Script, and Google Sheets on a mobile device (Apple IPad, IOS running 17.5.1).   Your help and expertise is greatly appreciated.

document.getElementById(name).value = ""; is not server side code.  It's' meant to be ran from the browser.

I’m confused!  What’s the point of having a “javascript.html” file if it can’t be run from the server side.    I thought the point of having a Javascript file in your project was to hide that code.    I must be missing something pertaining to server side and client side code.    And what does all the strike outs and edit statements have to do with coding? @Cooper -  I didn’t intend to have the code in a “javascript.html” file run on the server side.   What am I missing about project “.html” files for “CSS” and “Javascript” and the “.gs” files?

You seem to have a lot of questions but my comment refers to the fact that document refers to a clientside windows object and that does not run on google servers. It should be placed in an html file.  According to the code in your question you have clientside code in a .gs file.

@Cooper all my questions are an attempt to learn, understand and try to  figure out why my Javascript HTML file won’t execute.    I apologize for the document.get…..  in the gs file.   I mistakenly left in that statement in the .gs file in my many attempts to figure out why my Javascript wouldn’t execute.    Please ignore that statement as I understand it’s not server side code and doesn’t belong in the .gs file.   Please look at the “Javascript.html” file included and help me figure out why it won’t execute.     Thank you for your help and I apologize for the “document.get…” statement.

The user clicked function accepts a name and your are giving it an object in the google.script.run command

@Cooper - Thanks for your quick response.   I thought the beginner video I watched did exactly the same thing with the userClicked function.    Am I missing some syntax or is it impossible to send an object to a function.   The code snippet I posted shows only 1 element  but I’ll need to send at least 3 elements to the userClicked function.   How do I send an object to the function?    Thanks again for help.

It is possible to send an object but the gs function must accept the object and remove the name parameter value insdie the function.  Right now name is being populated with object and not object.uName.  Just read the code you provided

Hey @Cooper!  After your comments and suggestions I did some crucial scrutiny of my code and I was finally able to get it executing correctly.    Thank you very much for your patience and guidance.   Hope you are having a great day.    And,   thanks again for your patience and help.

On the page.html file change
function doStuff() {
      let userInfo = {};
      userInfo.uName =  document.getElementById("username").value   
      google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
      document.getElementById("username").value = "";
    }

To
function doStuff() {
      let userInfo = {};
      userInfo.uName =  document.getElementById("username").value   
      google.script.run.
      .withSuccessHandler(() => {
         document.getElementById("username").value = "";
      })
      .userClicked(userInfo.uName);
      
    }

And, on the code.gs file change
function userClicked(name) {
    Logger.log(name + " clicked the Button");
    document.getElementById(name).value = "";

To
function userClicked(name) {
    Logger.log(name + " clicked the Button");
}


Google Apps Script doesn't include a global document object, but this case is simple enough to be solved without any hassle. Still, if you want to parse HTML content on the server (by using the Google Apps Script engine instead of the web browser's JavaScript engine), you should declare your own document object or use a library that provides methods to parse HTML.
You might handle simple HTML content as a string and use string methods. In some cases, if the content is XHTML, you might use XML Service
